# How to keep a dynamic variable constant for a single user on a single page php

Tags: php, session, variables, dynamic, constants

how can i keep a variable constant in php only for the time when that particular page is being accessed.

also what is the scope of the define("xxx",0.0); Function in php.

I want to store a dynamic variable in php which can be constant as long as it is used by only one user.

can $_Session[]; can be used for this purpose?

Please help !

Comment: Do you mean it must remain constant for all users as long as there is atleast one user accessing the page?  If no users are accessing though then the variable may change?

Comment: I am storing a filename in the variable, i want that filename to remain constant for a particular user. The filename is updated by a script that gives latest file entered in that directory, so once i want the variable to remain constant as long as it is not stored in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All global variables you define have a scope of the current script for the current visitor; they are destroyed as soon as the script finishes processing. The same applies to constants.

Sessions are specific to a visitor and are retained across page-loads / script executions by that same user. When they get destroyed depends on the mechanism you are using (file / database) and the configuration of the web-server. Without any setup / special configuration you will probably notice that your variables cease to exist if you don't load or reload a page for about an hour.

Apart from sessions you can of course also use query strings to pass values around from one script (page-load) to another, but they will be visible to the visitor.

Comment: I am storing a filename in the variable, i want that filename to remain constant for a particular user. The filename is updated by a script that gives latest file entered in that directory, so once i want the variable to remain constant as long as it is not stored in the database

The problem with me is that the same script is refreshed 3 times for the same user, is there a way i can keep the filename constant?

Comment: @user1460822 Sure, just store it in a session variable. However, if you need to retain the information longer (across sessions), you would need to store it in a database.

Comment: can you please give me an example on how to implement it?

Comment: @user1460822 Just use `session_start();` at the top of every page before you output anything and store stuff in the session like `$_SESSION['filename'] = 'file_name`;`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a symlink for latest file in your script instead of storing value in a variable. so you can always use same value to access latest file.

Comment: i read about symlink , can you give me a small example , also , i have my script on a linux server and in the notes on php.net it says:

Note: For Windows only: This function will only function if the system you run PHP from is Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008 or greater. Windows versions prior to that does not support symbolic links.